# Docker: No ping command despite net-tools installed

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04, ping

Help appreciated to make me understand what is happening.

This is inside my container (based on Ubuntu 18.04):

```
root@T480:/home# ping
bash: ping: command not found
```

```
root@T480:/home# /bin/ping
bash: /bin/ping: command not found
```

Ok, maybe it's not installed. But:

```
# apt install net-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
net-tools is already the newest version (1.60+git20161116.90da8a0-1ubuntu1).
```

WTH?

Maybe `iputils-ping`, then:

```
# apt install iputils-ping
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
iputils-ping is already the newest version (3:20161105-1ubuntu3).
```

...but still:

```
# whereis ping
ping:
```

What is happening here?

Output of env inside the container:

```
# env
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
HOSTNAME=T480
PWD=/home
HOME=/root
TERM=xterm
SHLVL=1
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Comment: What is the output of `env` inside the container?

Comment: Added the output.

Comment: `find / -name "ping"`, see if it finds anything anywhere

Comment: It didn't find anything.

Comment: Your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Hi, can you try to remove iputils-ping, then apt autoremove, then install it again? In Ubuntu 18.04 iputils-ping should be enough for ping command.

Comment: `-y` just automatically answers "yes" so I don't know why that would help as it doesn't prompt anything. Instead, `--reinstall` did help although doesn't solve the original issue of missing binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the binaries are not there, but got this working by just:

`# apt install --reinstall iputils-ping`